# Why combined search bar and scope bar don't align correctly?

Tags: ios, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

First of all, quote form iOS User Interface Guidelines

> When a search bar is present, a scope bar can appear near it. The scope bar displays below the search bar, regardless of orientation, unless you use a search display controller in your code (for more information on the way this works, see UISearchDisplayController Class Reference). When you use a search display controller, the scope bar is displayed within the search bar to the right of the search field when the device is in landscape orientation (in portrait orientation, it’s below the search bar).

My problem is search input field doesn't align with scope bar, as showed in the picture.

[image: search input field doesn't align with scope bar]

Anyone knows what causes this?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I just double checked my own app and I see the same problem. I hadn't noticed it before. I would consider this a bug in iOS 7.x. Submit a bug report to Apple. Include a simple test app the demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I find the same issue. Report a bug with Apple.

Comment: Just filed a bug report to Apple #16991647